# Can I get FormResponse with only a response Id?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a confuse about getting formResponse.
Is the formResponse's Id unique among all form?

If not unique,the question is over.

If unique,then how can I get formResponse with only a response Id?

Now I can get formResponse with a formId and a formResponseId.

```js
var form = FormApp.openById(###FORM_ID###);
var formResponse = form.getResponse(###FORMRESPONSE_ID###);
```

I think the formId is unnecessary.
So is there any way to get a formResponse not using a formId?

```js
FormApp.getFormResponseById(###FORMRESPONSE_ID###);
```

Is this possiple?

Comment: I've been tried using a form object to get another form's response before,it worked,but I'm not sure if this way reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [getResponse() function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#getresponseresponseid) is only available for the Form object.

Looking at the [FormApp object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app) there is no such function available to acquire a form response across all forms.

I'm not able to answer your question whether the responses have unique IDs but without a function to acquire responses across all forms I think that answer is irrelevant.

Comment: It is ture that the getResponse() function is only available for the Form object.However,if the ID is unique,I can get the response without a form_id and just create an irrelevant form object to call getResponse() function.I've been tried using a form object to get another form's response before,it worked,but I'm not sure this way reliable or success everytime.

Comment: As it's not in the documentation I would not assume it is a reliable function.

Comment: I tried to do something similar about a year ago - I found no reliable solution and ended up building my own html form that ran .gs as the server side code and then I could add my own unique ID.